# How to concatenate a string with a variable in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have the following variables declared :

```
let addButton = $('#addMember');
```

I am trying to use this variable to locate all add button on the page without creating another variable like :

```
let allAddButton = $$('#addMember');
```

So for the sake of avoiding redundancy, I tried to create the variable allAddButton by declaring :

```
let allAddButton = join('$',addButton);
allAddButton.count().then(function{
//do something;
})
```

and it fails. The error is :

> Failed: ("$" + addButton).count is not a function

Can I somehow concatenate "$" with the predefined variables for this purpose?

Comment: I am confused by this. If I had multiple `#addMember` buttons, then the variable I would declare is `const allAddButton = $$('#addMember')`. If I wanted the first item, I would then grab it with `allAddButton.first()` or `allAddButton.get(0)`. In your join, it wouldn't make sense because it would always grab the first button so the count would always be 1.

Comment: If you have multiple `#addMember` then you first have a problem for having multiples elements with the same ID. An ID should be unique. You should use a class name here to select all your `.addMember` buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do like this

```
document.querySelectorAll("#addMember").forEach((e) => {
    e.doSomething
})
```

Thus selecting all with the correct selector and recursively adding what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks quite odd.

How about defining `ElementArrayFinder` like you did:

`let allAddButton = $$('#addMember');`

and if you need to get to paricular element use:

`allAddButton.first()` or `allAddButton.get(0)`?

Edit:
if you *really* need to use your approach, read about template literals:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals